# how to display HTML inside title HTML

Tags: html, tooltip, title

I need to display a HTML table as a part of tooltip on hover of some text.
Is there any way that we can use HTML tags to display a table inside title attribute of

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the title attribute supports HTML, instead go for a CSS solution like shown below, refer this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp) too, other options are jquery plugin to achieve the same.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 368px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center;">

  <p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

  <div class="tooltip">Hover over me
    <span class="tooltiptext">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  </span>
  </div>

  <p>Note that the position of the tooltip text isn't very good. Go back to the tutorial and continue reading on how to position the tooltip in a desirable way.</p>

</body>
```